# How to deal with a high order integral by using the elliptic integral?

Tags: integration, geometry, field-theory, elliptic-functions, elliptic-integrals

How do I solve this integral by using the elliptic integral?
$$\int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{a x^4+b x^3+c x^2+d x+ e}}$$
From some references on the elliptic functions, I only found some specific expressions, which cannot be directly applied to solve this integral. Hopefully someone can give me a hint or a general solution.

Comment: do you mean this here $$\int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{a x^4+b x^3+c x^2+d x+ e}}$$

Comment: this gives a elliptic integral of first kind

Comment: I know this is an elliptic integral of the first kind. I would like to know the analytic solution.

Comment: it is really very Long this solution

Comment: Do you know which book, paper or website mentions the details on this solution? Thanks.

Comment: i would try WolframAlpha

Comment: I tried Wolfram Alpha, but it fails to calculate it.

Comment: where can i plot it here? as an answer?